# Installing libgtk-3-dev, unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to install seahorse-3.16.0. When running ./configure, I get:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I've tried installing libgtk-3-dev with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Here's the output:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.32.4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.13.0~20140204) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried installing individual packages but they boil down to depending on something that is already present and all the way up to date. I've also tried installing libgtk-3-dev with aptitude, and I've run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade numerous times.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You have to downgrade some packages in order to meet the dependency requirements. You can get the downgrade versions from the error messages returned when calling apt-get install. For example, with the message

```
libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.0-2) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

you need to downgrade libglib2.0-0 to version 2.40.0-2 by

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0=2.40.0-2
```

before installing libglib2.0-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Some other packages you have to (re-)install before installing libgtk-3-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2=1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1 libcairo-gobject2=1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1

sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev

sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0=1.36.3-1ubuntu1 libpangocairo-1.0-0=1.36.3-1ubuntu1 libpangoft2-1.0-0=1.36.3-1ubuntu1 libpangoxft-1.0-0=1.36.3-1ubuntu1 gir1.2-pango-1.0=1.36.3-1ubuntu1

sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Comment: Ton-Chanh Le: how do you determine which versions of libraries are necessary to be (re)installed? I have a similar problem: see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059410/ubuntu-18-package-mismatch-libgtk-3-so-0-undefined-symbol-g-log-structured

Answer (score 4):

For ubuntu 18.04, activating the "recommended updates" in "Software & Updates" under "Updates" allowed me to install a newer version of libgtk-3-dev without downgrading anything.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 22.04 as at today

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 19.10. I first ran this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install libpcre3=2:8.39-12
```

And then all the packages installed Ok:

```
sudo apt-get -f install libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libatspi2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have searched broken packages in synaptic package manager and installed it.
It worked for me